# Archiva: Setting metadata properties

Tags: metadata, archiva

I cannot find the UI for setting archiva properties in the current version:

Have I missed something (logged in as admin)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with properties ? 
Maybe http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.4-M3/userguide/browsing.html see Metadata section ?